# Setting and getting values from map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have been searching on how should `new Map();` be used and how to assign values from both to the object or return the object.

I have found usage of `new Map();` on the MDN webdocs which is:

```js
let myMap = new Map();

myMap.set('key', 'value');

console.log(myMap.get('key'))
```

I have found in one of the posts it can be used as follows as well:

```js
let myMap = new Map();

myMap['key'] = 'value';

console.log(myMap['key']);
```

I have used `myMap['key']` way of of `new Map()` before but as i tried to return the map it seemed different.

This is example which shows difference between the two:

```js
let myMap0 = new Map();

let myMap1 = new Map();

myMap0.set('key','value');

myMap1['key'] = 'value';

console.log(myMap0);

console.log(myMap1);
```

Given example doesn't look alike in Google Chrome which is:
[image]

Overall this is really confusing for me as i am unsure which way is the way it is supposed to be used.

I got used to `myMap['key'] = 'value';` as this is how it works in Golang.

Additionaly i have found more solutions to the `myMap.set('key', 'value');`way of usage.

Comment: Both are correct, just different implementations. Using the set method is probably more common because it is more readable, people could confuse your map with a simple array if you use the square bracket notation.

Comment: The `set` method is the correct way. Otherwise you’ll always have a `size` of `0` and no entries, as you see in the console. You’re just adding properties, but not entries.

Comment: Assigning to the `Map` object is very likely not what you want. Just use a normal object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Map` has two distinct storage areas:

1. The properties of the object (which all objects have)
2. The entries of the `Map`

When you use `myMap['key'] = 'value'`, you're assigning to the properties. When you use `myMap.set('key', 'value')`, you're assigning to the entries.

The entries of a `Map` are special because they don't require the keys to be strings, and since they're stored separately from the object properties, you don't have to worry about any name collisions with properties like `toString` or `valueOf`.

`Map.prototype.set` is the preferred way to set an entry in the `Map`, because it utilizes the features of the `Map`. Otherwise, if you just assign to the object's properties, you might as well be using a plain object instead.

Comment: I have found Object.entries to work on `'myMap['key'] = 'value'` (which behaves like an object) and for `myMap.set('key', 'value') ` : `myMap.entries()` which is not so great.

Comment: @HowToGo `[...myMap.entries()]` or `Array.from(myMap.entries())`? Works just like `Object.entries`. With `Array.from` you can even provide a mapping function.